# ColdFusion and REST

Tags: rest, iis, coldfusion

According to [this blog entry](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/rest-support-in-coldfusion-part-i), REST is available in ColdFusion.
However, I have multiple sites, so when I navigate to

localhost/rest/Example/hello

I get "Hello World", but if I go to

http://mysite.com/rest/Example/hello

I get HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Requested URL http://mysite.com:80/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll

If I go to the IP address, I get "Hello World".

Aaron posted a comment referring to [bug 3348765](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3348765), but I'm not sure that helps me get this first Proof-Of-Concept working.

Q: How do I get REST to work in ColdFusion if I have multiple sites defined in IIS?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/rest-support-in-coldfusion-part-i tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `mysite.com` is very unlucky domain name since lots of people trying to use it for learning or testing purposes. That's just a website and most likely they don't have a ColdFusion 10 REST webservice.

Your problem with `localhost` seems to be the web-server issue. If you open `http://localhost`, do you see the same website as `http://127.0.0.1`? These could easily be two different virtual hosts (websites, in terms of IIS).

Solution would be to check how your ColdFusion is installed with your IIS. Even better solution would be to set up some virtual host for playing with code, for example I've got virtual local hosts like localhost.coldfusion, localhost.railo, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sergii.  I was hoping that REST was going to be simple.  Setting up virtual hosts is too much effort for a proof-of-concept.

Comment: @Phillip Nah, that was just a general advice. What you need is to use the host where CF10 is configured with your IIS.